# google cloud storage and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, google-cloud-storage, jwt

I'm building a mobile app with html/js/phonegap/angularjs. I would like my users to be able to upload photos from their phones directly to google cloud storage. How do I do this?

I've seen this jwt stuff https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount
but I've also found this approach using cors http://codeartists.com/post/36892733572/how-to-directly-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-your
I also don't want my users to have to authenticate or anything. I just want a place to store my app's photos.

An answer with node.js/express code would be awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like nobody is working on this. I've found this repo but there are no examples on how to use it. https://github.com/chanthus/cordova-plugin-file-transfer-gcs